# React SPA API endpoint from a php controller opens a blank SPA page

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, single-page-application

I've set up a single page application that makes use of controllers (Written in PHP) to fetch data from the API.
So far I have had no issues, data populates table, upon selecting table element it re-renders with new url and partial data (Mainly ID) but it throws me an error when trying to fetch user/{id} data.
Upon testing similar links with localhost....../api/company/user it shows data as json, however this particular link for localhost...../api/company/user/{UserIDHere} just re-renders the page with menu ontop and body is completely blank. I am at a complete loss what could be the issue.

So far I made sure that the API GET link is not the same as route.
Currently links are as follows..

```
/company
/company/users
/company/users/123
```

And the GET request is done with 
/company/user
and /company/user/123   *Notice the missing S for users*

In theory it should not produce any issues, especially when making a get request to:

/company/user - fetches all the users with associated ID's and etc
however /company/user/{userID}  provides an error that there's an unexpected token <  (As in it generates HTML instead of Json)

I've already tested out the API endpoints using postman and it works great, fetches all the data for both requests.. Code provided below:

This is using postman, for the GET "/company/user"..:

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"total":3},"data":[{"id":118,"firstName":"Test123","lastName":"Driver 2","fullName":"Test123 Driver 2","email":"driver2@abc.com","type":"emp","typeName":"Employee","role":"driv","roleName":"Driver","birthDate":null},{"id":139,"firstName":"dsghsdhsd12511","lastName":"sagsdh","fullName":"dsghsdhsd12511 sagsdh","email":"asgsagas@fsaf.sf","type":"con","typeName":"Contractor","role":"acco","roleName":"Accountant","birthDate":null},{"id":122,"firstName":"123321424","lastName":"Driver 3","fullName":"123321424 Driver 3","email":"test@fsafs.sf","type":"emp","typeName":"Employee","role":"driv","roleName":"Driver","birthDate":null}]}
```

This is using Postman for the GET "company/user/118"

```
  {"status":"OK","data":{"id":118,"firstName":"Test123","lastName":"Driver 2","fullName":"Test123 Driver 2","email":"driver2@abc.com","type":"emp","typeName":"Employee","role":"driv","roleName":"Driver","birthDate":null,"ssn":null,"documents":[],"access":{"accounting":true,"company":false,"dispatch":false,"equipment":false,"safety":false},"accountId":null}}
```

And this is the requests I use to get the data in React code

```
getUsers() {
Api.get(this.controller, "/company/user", data => {
this.setState({ users: data });
 console.log(this.state.users);
});
}

getUser(id) {
if (id) {
Api.get1(this.controller, "/company/user/" + id, data => this.setState({ user: data }));
}
}
```

Get Users works great.
Get user does not at all.

Everywhere else the links are all to /company/users 
or as in case of selected table element

```
 <Route exact path={"/company/users"} component={() => <UserControlPage/>} />
        <Route path={"/company/users/:id"} component={UserControlPage} />
```

This is the CompanyController functions that get called :

```
$app->get('/' . API . '/' . self::NAME . "/user", function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($c) {
  return Api::get($c->con['api'], $c->log, $request, $response, "/" . self::NAME . "/user", $c->con['session']);
});

$app->get(API . '/' . self::NAME . "/user/{id}", function (Request $request, Response $response, $pp) use ($c) {
  return Api::get($c->con['api'], $c->log, $request, $response, "/" . self::NAME . "/user/" . Api::pathParameter($pp, 'id'), $c->con['session']);
});
```

I expected that upon selecting an element in the table it would re-render the page, pick the ID, get all users for a list to be produced on the left (This part works) and then would only produce associated information for the rest of the body, however for the later I get one succesful request (For all users) and second one produces error message:

```
ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Do let me know if the formatting is wrong / you need specific files or information, I've been troubleshooting this for last 3 days and I can not figure it out.

Comment: If it makes no sense I can pretty much understand it, but I am mainly looking for even general advice or suggestion as to what else I could check, as it only seems to be issue with this specific endpoint (If the endpoint does not exist, I do get an error from PHP saying method not allowed) but for this case, its just a reload of SPA with failed GET

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after ages of siphoning through what could be wrong it still led me to believe its more than likely issues with the controllers.... 
ATTENTION TO DETAIL was my problem..

Turns out, the only thing was a missing '/'

Basically turning this:

```
$app->get(API . '/' . self::NAME . "/user/{id}", function (Request $request, Response $response, $pp) use ($c) {
  return Api::get($c->con['api'], $c->log, $request, $response, "/" . self::NAME . "/user/" . Api::pathParameter($pp, 'id'), $c->con['session']);
});
```

Into this:

```
$app->get('/' . API . '/' . self::NAME . "/user/{id}", function (Request $request, Response $response, $pp) use ($c) {
  return Api::get($c->con['api'], $c->log, $request, $response, "/" . self::NAME . "/user/" . Api::pathParameter($pp, 'id'), $c->con['session']);
});
```

Fixed the issue.. And yes, it was only a **/** (A forwardslash)  missing before API all along.

Yes I did fix the remainder of controllers as I seemingly copied one wrong, and thus I messed all of them up.

Thanks for everyone who checked out the question!!